# How to register two modules to ng-app?

Tags: angularjs

In my application I have two modules, which are used for routing. Here is the code of it

**//Module1:**

```
 angular.module('phonecat', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',   controller: PhoneListCtrl}).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html', controller: PhoneDetailCtrl}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/phones'});
}]);
```

**Module2:**

```
angular.module("computer",[]).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/test',{templateUrl:'mypath/my-list.html',controller:ComputerListCtrl});
}]);
```

As per angularJS document, I have to register these modules into **ng-app**, like this

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecat">
```

But in the above code, at a time I can register only one module, that is, phoneCat moudle or computer module. Because of this, I am able load only one module data into the application.

So please guide me, how can I register both the module into ng-app, during bootsrap or is there any other way I can do this.

Comment: `angular.module('app', ['phonecat','computer'])`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can create a top level module that will have your two modules as injected dependencies:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['phonecat', 'computer']);
```

and then in your html use:`ng-app="app"`