# AngularJS custom components with module names different from the one in ng-App in the HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How can the HTML page recognize AngularJS custom components whose module names are different from the one in ng-App in the HTML page?

Many thanks in advance.

P.S. I found my answer at the following link:
[How to register two modules to ng-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228508/how-to-register-two-modules-to-ng-app)

Comment: They are defined in the declarations array in the `.module`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to register two modules to ng-app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228508/how-to-register-two-modules-to-ng-app)

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is a duplicate of How to register two modules to ng-app.

Answer (score 0):

By custom components I'm assuming you're referring to angular directives.
That depends if you have the module containing the directive injected into your main module.

```
let module1 = angular.module('module1',[]).directive(/*directive code here*/);
let module2 = angular.module('module2', ['one']);
```

In the above scenario, `module2` is aware of the directives in `module1`

Comment: By 'one', do you mean 'module1'?